# Python multithreaded server - issues with client server communication

Tags: python, html, multithreading, server

I'm trying to build a simple multithreaded server that when queried via a browser replies with the html page being requested or a 404 page.

Here is my code:

```
from socket import *
import thread

def handler(connectionSocket,addr):
    try:
        message = connectionSocket.recv(2048) 
        filename = message.split()[1] 
        f = open(filename[1:], 'r')
        outputdata = f.read()

        #Send one HTTP header line into socket
        connectionSocket.send("\nHTTP/1.0 200 OK\n\n")

        #Send the content of the requested file to the client
        connectionSocket.send(outputdata)

        #Close client socket
        f.close()
        connectionSocket.close()
    except IOError:
        #Send response message for file not found
        print "404 Not Found"

        #Send over 404 page
        f = open("404.php",'r')
        outputdata = f.read()
        connectionSocket.send("\nHTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\n\n")
        connectionSocket.send(outputdata)

        #Close client socket
        f.close()
        connectionSocket.close()


def main():
    #Prepare a sever socket
    serverPort = 6789
    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    serverSocket.bind(('',serverPort))
    serverSocket.listen(1)
    print "Starting server on port: " + str(serverPort) + ". User <CTRL-C> to stop"

    while True:
        #Establish the connection
        print 'Ready to serve...'
        connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
        print '...connected from:', addr
        thread.start_new_thread(handler,(connectionSocket,addr))

    serverSocket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

when I query for, say, helloworld.html, I receive the webpage, but the server seems to have connected 4 times, as shown below. After the page is brought up, it stays on "Ready to serve..." for a few minutes and then gets the error.

```
Starting server on port: 6789. User <CTRL-C> to stop
Ready to serve...
...connected from: ('127.0.0.1', 61382)
Ready to serve...
...connected from: ('127.0.0.1', 61386)
Ready to serve...
...connected from: ('127.0.0.1', 61387)
Ready to serve...
...connected from: ('127.0.0.1', 61388)
Ready to serve...
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function handler at 0x10051a410>
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "web_server2.py", line 13, in handler
    filename = message.split()[1]
IndexError: list index out of rangeUnhandled exception in thread started by <function handler at 0x10051a410>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web_server2.py", line 13, in handler
    filename = message.split()[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function handler at 0x10051a410>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web_server2.py", line 13, in handler
    filename = message.split()[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "web_server2.py", line 58, in <module>
    main()
  File "web_server2.py", line 51, in main
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 206, in accept
    sock, addr = self._sock.accept()
```

From the error traceback, it seems that the program connects and sends the page, then thinks it's connected again, but when no query is sent, the array is empty and it exits with a bounds error.

Similarly, when I query for a page not there and receive my 404 page:

```
Starting server on port: 6789. User <CTRL-C> to stop
Ready to serve...
...connected from: ('127.0.0.1', 55032)
Ready to serve...
...connected from: ('127.0.0.1', 55033)
Ready to serve...
404 Not Found
...connected from: ('127.0.0.1', 55059)
Ready to serve...
...connected from: ('127.0.0.1', 55061)
Ready to serve...
...connected from: ('127.0.0.1', 55063)
Ready to serve...
...connected from: ('127.0.0.1', 55065)
Ready to serve...
...connected from: ('127.0.0.1', 55067)
Ready to serve...
...connected from: ('127.0.0.1', 55069)
Ready to serve...
...connected from: ('127.0.0.1', 55071)
Ready to serve...
...connected from: ('127.0.0.1', 55073)
Ready to serve...
...connected from: ('127.0.0.1', 55075)
Ready to serve...
...connected from: ('127.0.0.1', 55077)
Ready to serve...
...connected from: ('127.0.0.1', 55079)
Ready to serve...
...connected from: ('127.0.0.1', 55093)
Ready to serve...
404 Not Found
...connected from: ('127.0.0.1', 55095)
Ready to serve...
404 Not Found
```

It connects multiple times, but only passes through the ioexception part 3 times since there is only 3 prints of "404 Not Found". But now, the server doesn't exit out as it did with the helloworld.html page, it stays exactly as is above and when queried again with a non existent page, I get another 404. But when queried for helloworld.html, it displays it then exits with the same error as above.

Any help on where to look for the bug would be great. I can tell from testing it that it seems to have something to do with how I'm handling the i/o, but I'm not sure what seems to be the issue. This is my first server program and looking to learn a lot more about it. Thanks!

Comment: try printing `message` before splitting it.

Comment: not related: you shouldn't send a newline before the http headers...

Comment: @CristiFati when I print message right before splitting it, I get three connections, then the printed message (GET /helloworld.html HTTP/1.1 ... etc) then two more connections (i.e. "...connected from: " )and then an exit with the same bounds error.

So it seems that it's hitting the "print '...connected from:', addr" three time before it actually prints the message. then it hits the same line once more after properly executing during that one connection.

Comment: @mata noted. I'll fix that, thanks.

Comment: I remember (hope that i'm not talking crap here), that in order to avoid MITM attacks newer (since early this year) browsers send their request (at least on encrypted channels) data in 2 parts (also include a _G_ character), yielding a HTTP 400 response on some old HTTP servers (that had to be updated). You could try with python's (2.7) BaseHTTPServer that was ok.